# Is there a relation between the size of the domain/range of a function and its computability?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, recursion

This was a question given in a course, without answer. The referenced literature (just a few books) do not cover it, unfortunately.

I think there is no relation with the range as the range of the Halting problem is {0,1} and the range of the successor function is infinite. But I feel like I'm missing some subtleties here.

Comment: Well, for one the domain must be infinite; else, the function is computable.

Comment: If the range is empty or contains a single element, the function is also computable. Nevertheless, two elements already suffice for uncomputability (as you have noted).

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate why these two claims are true? Hard-coding? And for the range, what if it is a partial function?

Comment: Exactly. If the domain is finite, then you can simply hardcode all function values. Ad the second claim: if the range is empty, then the domain must be empty (otherwise it is not a function), and we are back to the finite domain case; if the range has only one element, you can hardcode this as your algorithm's answer. Finally, regarding partial functions: any partial function becomes a function by restricting its domain; thus, it suffices to consider only (non-partial) functions.

Comment: Okay but if it's domain isn't decidable you can't know whether or not it returns a value yes or no, so even with one element ... unless you mean that 'undefined' is an other element, like with the Halting function that would not stop?

Comment: @dkaeae Write an answer? You may want to clarify there are [two different definitions/usage of domain and range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Basic_concepts).

Comment: @LorenFrancis That's correct. If a partial function has $\{n\}$ as its range, it is computable if and only if its domain is recursively enumerable.

Answer (score 3):

(**Note:** As mentioned by Apass.Jack in the comments, there are apparently two different usages of the terms "domain" and "range". In this answer, I adopt the usages which I am more familiar with. That is, given a function $f\colon X \to Y$ (i.e., $f \subseteq X \times Y$), $X$ is the *domain of $f$* in the sense that $f(x)$ is defined for all $x \in X$; similarly, the *range* (or *codomain*) $Y$ is a set such that $f(x) \in Y$ for all $x \in X$. Additionally, every function is total; partial functions are explicitly denoted as such.)

---

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a function. The question is: What can we say about the computability of $f$ (strictly) based on $|X|$ and $|Y|$? The following is more or less a structured breakdown of what I have written in the comments:

### Domain

- Case 1: $|X|$ is finite. Then the values $f(x)$ of $x \in X$ may be hardcoded (e.g., as a lookup table) in an algorithm to compute $f$.
- Case 2: $|X|$ is infinite. There are plenty of both computable and uncomputable functions in this case.

### Range

If $Y$ is such that the image $\text{im}(f) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in X \}$ of $f$ is a *proper* subset of $Y$, then there is not much that can be said about $f$ (e.g., $Y$ could be an infinite set but $f = \{ \}$ the empty function; see Case 1 below). Thus, let us assume $\text{im}(f) = Y$ holds.

- Case 1: $|Y| = 0$. Then $f$ must be the empty function $\{ \}$, which indicates $|X| = 0$; see "Domain", Case 1.
- Case 2: $|Y| = 1$. $f$ is computable by an algorithm which ignores its input and outputs the only possible value for $f$.
- Case 3: $|Y| \ge 2$ but $|Y|$ finite. An example of an uncomputable $f$ is, for instance, the membership relation for the halting problem (as mentioned in the question) or any non-recursive (i.e., undecidable) language; similarly, a computable $f$ would be the membership relation for a recursive (i.e., decidable) language.
- Case 4: $|Y|$ infinite. As in case 3, there are both computable and uncomputable choices for $f$. For example, $X = Y$ and $f = \text{Id}_X$ is trivially computable. An uncomputable example for $f$ (off the top of my head) would be the [busy beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy-beaver).

It is possible to extend these results if further assumptions are made about $X$, $Y$, and $f$. In the general case, however, this is as much (and it is not much, I know) we can say about the computability of $f$.

---

If we are dealing with a partial function $f \subseteq X \times Y$ instead, note there is always a (maximal) $X' \subseteq X$ such that $f \subseteq X' \times Y$ is a (total) function $X' \to Y$. As pointed out by chi in the comments, it might be tempting to say we may simply generalize the above discussion by considering the total restriction of $f$ instead. This does not work, however, since, for example, the partial function $f \subseteq \mathbb{N}_0 \times \{ 1 \}$ with $f(x) = 1$ if and only if TM number $x$ does not halt is not computable, despite its image having a single element (cnf. "Range", Case 2). Nevertheless, note this is the only case in which the generalization fails.

Comment: In case 2, as the OP mentioned in a comment, we need slightly more. If $f$ is partial with range $\{n\}$, then $f$ may or may not be computable. Precisely, such $f$ is computable iff its domain is r.e. . The very last comment is misleading (IMO) since $X'$ might be a non-r.e. set, so the discussion does not really extend.

Comment: @chi Duly noted. (Partial functions... ugh...) This is the only case in which the generalization fails though, isn't it?

Comment: Note that your last $f$ is computable, since the halting problem is r.e. ! To compute $f(x)$ run machine number $x$. When (and if) that halts, return $1$. To craft a non computable $f$ you need, for instance, require $f(x)=1$ when TM $x$ does not halt ($f$ being undefined otherwise).